# Server 2008R2 Allow non-admins to remote into server without terminal services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have a server that only a couple people will be using so I have not purchased any CAL's for it.  As I understand, this means I can not use "terminal services" or Remote Desktop Services.

How can I make it so that normal users can remote into it just like I can as an admin?  I have added them to the remote desktop users group but that did not help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the message they are getting? Is it prompting for logon details and then rejecting? What OS are the clients on, and are you forcing Network Level Authentication for the Remote Desktop?

Comment: The clients are on windows 7.  If they are part of the remote desktop user group then it will ask for log on info, then open up the remote desktop window but give the error below.  If they are not part of the group it does not even open that new window.  I am only allowing connections from computers with Network Level Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to the System Properties. Here you will find the tab named Remote. On this tab you can select the remote users

Comment: They are already added.  I get the error "To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the Allow log on through Terminal Services right..."  I have looked for this but since I do not want to use Terminal Services and do not have the roll enabled, I can't do that.

Comment: it could be that there is a group policy that is not allowing them to logon - to test this deny the group policy applying to the server...

Comment: You need to select the users (or groups) that can log on. You also need to set the administrative flag in your RDP connection file.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Remote Desktop (in the System properties) and placing the users in the `Administrators` or `Remote Desktop Users` local groups should be enough, as the default policy settings for a Windows system allow RDP access to members of those two groups; as long as you don't want more than 2 concurrent connections to the server, it will happily handle them without need for any additional licensing.

If the server is in a domain, you should check applied GPOs, which could be restricting RDP access to it. You can use `gpresult.exe` for this. The relevant settings are in `Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment`.